# AngularJS - Remove hash # using $locationProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, .htaccess

I used `$locationProvider` to remove `hashtag #` from this `url`

```
http://localhost/angular-phonecat/app/#/phones
```

using the following code:

```
phonecatApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider.
    when('/phones', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-list.html', controller: 'PhoneListCtrl'}).
    when('/phones/:phoneId', {templateUrl: 'partials/phone-detail.html', controller: 'PhoneDetailCtrl'}).
    otherwise({redirectTo: '/phones'});

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

and in `index.html` added this in the head

```
<base href="/angular-phonecat/app/">
```

this worked and my current url is:

```
http://localhost/angular-phonecat/app/phones
```

But when I directly access this `url` it is not showing the webpage because it is not calling the `index.html` file. Instead, it is showing the contents of `/app/phones` directory

[image]

I tried by creating an `.htaccess` file also

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule     ./index.html [L]
```

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Try above tuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a small error in your rule, the rewrite rule requires one more parameter.

Furthermore, when you write `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` you prevent redirection if a directory with this name exists. Since `/anular-phonecat/app/phones` exist you need to also remove this line.

You dont need the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/index\.php|/img|/js|/css|/robots\.txt|/favicon\.ico)` condition, since files won't be redirecte thanks to the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition

The result is:

```
RewriteEngine   On
RewriteBase     /angular-phonecat/app/ 
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule     .* ./index.html [L]
```

*Edited response based on comments*

Comment: You're app is a the root level of your server right? (e.g. http://localhost/index.html)? What's the error?

Comment: Then you need to either remove RewriteBase or set it to  '/angular-phonecat/app/'

Comment: KK now you edited the post i see another issue. You also need to remove the `RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` which prevents redirection when the folder exists

Comment: RewriteBase     /angular-phonecat/app/